# How to extract an element from a tuple in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I have the following tuples:

```
type Id = Int
type Name = String
type FSK = Int
type Movie = (Id, Name, FSK)
```

now I want to define a function that extracts a movie from a given list like that:

```
extract :: Id -> [Movie] -> (Maybe Movie, [Movie])
extract = .... ??
```

so that when I give an id and a list of Movies, it extracts:
1) Nothing +the given list, if the id is found 
2) Just + the movie , and the new list without that movie, if the given id is found, and the movie is deleted from the list

example:

```
*Main> extract 0 [(1,"Matrix",16),(2,"Gladiator",0)]
(Nothing,[(1,"Matrix",16),(2,"Gladiator",0)])
*Main> extract 1 [(1,"Matrix",16),(2,"Gladiator",0)]
(Just (1,"Matrix",16),[(2,"Gladiator",0)])
```

How should I define the function?

Comment: How far have you gotten so far?  `.... ??` isn't much of an attempt.  Usually you start by pattern matching on something you have, e.g. your `[Movie]` list.

Comment: What does it do for `[]`? What does it do for `movie:xs | movie == id`? What does it do for any other case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
extract :: Id -> [Movie] -> (Maybe Movie, [Movie])
extract id []                 = (Nothing, [])
extract id ((fid, n, f):list) | fid == id =  (Just (fid, n, f), list)
                              | otherwise =  (found, (fid, n, f):tail)
                              where (found, tail) = extract id list
```